# Mac OS: Latest PHP version installed, but older version used

Tags: php, macos, terminal, version

I've installed the latest PHP version (7.2) on my Mac OS, however, by typing in "php -v" in the terminal, I always get "PHP 5.5.38" as response.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you have got two installations of php now? I think you have to STOP old from old MAMP and start the new.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay did OP mention MAMP anywhere ?

Comment: Generally people use MAMP with MacOS

Comment: I dont : i have multiple php/mysql/apache and link/restart services depending on which project i am currently working.

Comment: What version does phpinfo say you run if you run `phpinfo();` on a local webpage? If you have a missmatch have a look at this page https://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli